# PHP Mongodb date range

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I do a date range search with php and mongodb.

in my db i have the following format :-

```
time:"2019-11-15T18:24:31.552363Z"
```

and in php I'm trying the following :-

```
$startOfDay = new MongoDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2019-01-09T00:00:00')));
$endOfDay = new MongoDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2020-01-09T23:59:59')));

$where = array("rxInfo.time" => array('$gt' => $startOfDay, '$lt' => $endOfDay));

$query = $m->nodes->$nodeName->find($where);

foreach ( $query as $current ){    
  $Ptemperature = $current["object"]["TempC_SHT"];    
}
```

But keep getting nothing back.

I think my start and end date format is wrong but can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: instead of using the new MongoDate try this https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php

Comment: Hi thx, i had dome trouble getting the bson working, troubleshooting the following just worked.

from 
$startOfDay = new MongoDate(date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2019-01-09T00:00:00'))); 

to 
$startOfDay = '2019-01-09T00:00:00';

Thanks

Comment: Your range misses the fist and last second of the day. As a general rule, use a half-open range. In this case, it means `X >= start of day` and `X < start of next day`.